# Calling R functions directly from VisEvents

Tags: r, visnetwork

I am trying to set up an interactive network graph using visNetwork and want to display some data which is being processed in a function in R when I click on the nodes. How can I achieve this using visEvents:

I have tried directly calling a function to simply print hello world but it shows up an error:

> Error in class(graph) %in% c("visNetwork", "visNetwork_Proxy") :
>   argument "graph" is missing, with no default

This is what I am trying currently:

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
+     visEvents(select = "function() {
+ alert('Hello')})
```